# Javascript - AJAX Request Cancelled after a While over SSL

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using the Prototype JS framework to do AJAX calls over an SSL connection. At first, the AJAX performs fine. However, if the page is live for more than 10 seconds or so, the AJAX requests fail to return successfully and have a status of 0, or 'canceled' in the Network Inspector...

[image]

This happens across multiple browsers and I've tried other solutions relating to .gz files, all to no avail.

Another hints is that once the AJAX requests begin to fail, the green lock symbol turns to a grey triangle with a warning symbol (insecure content). Any pointers please?

Comment: What are the URLs you are actually using? I know I can see the path in the first column, but I don't think you can make AJAX requests to non-https when using https

Comment: Hi Ian, thx. I've looked at the URL requests and they all begin https://

Answer (score 0):

The AJAX requests were being redirected by our european switcher. Changed this:

```
   $clearCurrentUrl = str_replace(array('/index.php'), '', Mage::helper('core/url')>getCurrentUrl());
   $clearRedirectUrl = str_replace(array('/index.php'), '', $redirectUrl);
```

to this...

```
   $clearCurrentUrl = str_replace(array('/index.php', 'https://', 'http://'), '', Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl());
   $clearRedirectUrl = str_replace(array('/index.php', 'https://', 'http://'), '', $redirectUrl);
```

And it works a charm now! :) Thx folks.